# Saptharishis for each Manvantra

Tags: vashishta, vishwamitra, saptarshi, vedvyas

Can someone compile a list with scriptural references for the Saptharishis of each manvantra?

Comment: You can check Viṣṇu Purāṇa (3.1), the saptarṣis of 13 manvataras (from 2nd to 14th) are mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Shiva Purana 5.34](https://getwisdom.in/index.php?flg=N&pmd=W&mdi=L&thm=2&vip=puran+eng&puran=4+Shiv&sec=10&chap=34&pn=1623&cod=shiva&bn1=chap&bn=page) and [Vishnu Purana 3.1](https://getwisdom.in/index.php?flg=N&pmd=W&mdi=L&thm=2&vip=puran+eng&puran=3+Vishnu&sec=3&chap=1&pn=1&cod=vishnu&bn1=chap&bn=page). There might be a slight difference due to Kalpa-Bheda.

Here's a list.:

[image]

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: There is a female Saptarishi Kavya.

Comment: Kāvya is not female. Rishi Shukra aka Ushana because of being a Kavi (Poet) is called Kavya. See Brahmanda Purana 2.32.98.: 98-100. The following sages are the sons of Īśvaras. Understand them. **Kāvya (Śukra),** Bṛhaspati, Kaśyapa, Cyavana, Utathya, Vāmadeva, Apāsya, Uśija, Kardama, Viśravas, Śakti, Vālakhilyas and Arvata. These sages are said to have attained the state of sages by means of penance. Understand Ṛṣikas, the sons of sages born of womb.

Comment: However, sometimes Kavya is also called as the son of Angiras.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifiying

Comment: You are welcome. ..